# Calculating expected value of infimum of two point distrubution

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expected-value, supremum-and-infimum

Let $(X_k)$ be a sequence of random variables as following : $P(X_i=-1)=q$ and $P(X_i=1)=1-q$. I want to calculate $$E[\inf\{n:X_1+X_2+...+X_n>0\}]$$

**My work so far**

Let's denote $Y(x)=\inf\{X_1+X_2+...+X_n>x\}$

Then we want to calculate $E[Y(1)]$

$$E[Y(x)]=E[Y(x)|X_1=-1]P(X_1=-1)+E[Y(x)|X_1=1]P(X_1=1)=$$
$$=E[Y(x)|X_1=-1]q+1-q$$

And now I have a little troubles with calculating $E[Y(x)|X_1=-1]$. Could you please tell me if I'm going in right direction ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_n:=k+\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and $T_z:=\inf\{n\ge 1: S_n=z\}$. Then
$$
\mathsf{P}_0(T_1=1)=1-q,
$$
and for $n\ge 1$,
\begin{align}\label{1}\tag{1}
\mathsf{P}_0(T_1=2n+1)&=q\mathsf{P}_{-1}(T_1=2n)=\frac{q}{n}\mathsf{P}_{-2}(S_{2n}=0) \\
&=\frac{q}{n}\binom{2n}{n-1}q^{n-1}(1-q)^{n+1},
\end{align}
where $\mathsf{P}_k$ is the law of $S_n$ starting at $k$. Therefore, for $q<1/2$,
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}T_1&=\sum_{n\ge 0}(2n+1)\mathsf{P}_0(T=2n+1) \\
&=(1-q)+q\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{2n+1}{n}\binom{2n}{n-1}q^{n-1}(1-q)^{n+1} \\
&=\frac{1}{1-2q}.
\end{align}
Obviously, for $q\ge 1/2$, $\mathsf{E}T=\infty$.

---

For the second equality in \eqref{1} we used the [fact](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Erhofstad/monthly753-756-hofstad.pdf) that
$$
\mathsf{P}_{-1}(T_1=k)=\mathsf{P}_{-2}(T_0=k)=\frac{2}{k}\mathsf{P}_{-2}(S_k=0).
$$

Comment: what does those subscripts mean ? for instance $P_0, P_{-1}$ ?

Comment: I don't quite understand how this line explains subscripts in probability

Comment: I fixed the definition of $S_n$; it should be clear now.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand. You defined $S_n$ using $k$ but what is this $k$ exactly ? Also I don't quite get those subscripts in probabilities. I think most handy solution would be if you just write definition of $P_i=...$

Comment: $k$ is the initial value of $S_n$. The notation $\mathsf{P}_k$ means just that. Alternatively, we could define $S_{k,n}=k+\ldots$ and $T_{k,z}=\inf\{\ldots:S_{k,n}=z\}$ and write something like $\mathsf{P}(T_{-1,1}=k)=\mathsf{P}(T_{-2,0}=k)=\ldots$. I used the former notation because of the referenced paper.